# Removing last row of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm kinda new on the scene and I was hoping you guys could help me...

I'm a beginner in java programming and I think Iwent over my head with this one.

My programms is working perfectly except for one little detail that annoys me. I have a JTable with a button on the first column that allows to delete this row from the table. Its working well except when I try to delete the last row of the table, the button stay there and then the table freeze and i can't delete any rows because i receive a "Out of bound Exception" . But, when I use the command table.getRowCount());

Before and after the removal of the line, the table "knows" that a line was removed but as i said, the button stay there. The screenshots in thumbnails show the situation before and after clicking the button next to the "Year" cell.

[image: before]
[image: after]

It's good to add that i'm adding rows in the table from a button outside the table.

Heres my code:
Main.java

```
static String [] title = {"X","Nom","SRM","Rend.","%","Kg",};
static Object[][] contenu;
static DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(contenu, title);
static JTable tableauGrains = new JTable(model1);

tableauGrains.getColumn("X").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
tableauGrains.getColumn("X").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
```

ButtonRenderer.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer{

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table, Object value,
                                                    boolean isSelected, boolean isFocus,
                                                    int row, int col) {
        Color beige = new Color(218, 217, 158);
        setBackground(beige);
        //On écrit dans le bouton ce que contient la cellule
        setText((value != null) ? value.toString() : "");
        //on retourne notre bouton
        return this;
    }
}
```

ButtonEditor.java

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    protected JButton button;
    private DeleteButtonListener bListener = new DeleteButtonListener();

    /**
     * Constructeur avec une checkBox
     * @param checkBox
     * @param count
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
        //Par défaut, ce type d'objet travaille avec un JCheckBox
        super(checkBox);
        //On crée à nouveau notre bouton
        button = new JButton();
        button.setOpaque(true);
        //On lui attribue un listener
        button.addActionListener(bListener);

    }

      public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            //On précise le numéro de ligne à notre listener
            bListener.setRow(row);
            //Idem pour le numéro de colonne
              //On passe aussi le tableau en paramètre pour des actions potentielles
            bListener.setTable(table);

            //On réaffecte le libelle au bouton
            button.setText( (value == null) ? "" : value.toString() );
            //On renvoie le bouton
            return button;
          }

      class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {

            private int row;
            private JTable table;

            public void setRow(int row){this.row = row;}
            public void setTable(JTable table){this.table = table;}

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if(table.getRowCount() > 0){
                //On affiche un message
                System.out.println("coucou du bouton: "+ ((JButton)event.getSource()).getText() );
                ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(this.row);
                    ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
                         }
          }
       }        
    }
```

I'm sorry about the french comments, its my native language.

It's seems like the JTable is not "refreshing" itself after the removal of the last row.

I'm I out of my league here ?

Thank you very much and sorry about the long post, i tried to give you the most informations possible.

Djosimd 
EDIT:

> Execption pile after trying to click the 11th row after deleteing the
>   row 12 :
>
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11 >= 11    at
>   java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

---

**SSCCE:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FooGui {
   static String[] title = { "X", "Nom", "SRM", "Rend.", "%", "Kg"};
   static Object[][] contenu;
   // !! static DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(contenu, title);
   static DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(title, 0);

   static JTable tableauGrains = new JTable(model1);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      tableauGrains.getColumn("X").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
      tableauGrains.getColumn("X").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         String btnText = "Btn " + (i + 1);
         Object[] rowData = {btnText, "", "", "", "", ""};
         model1.addRow(rowData);
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(tableauGrains));
   }
}

class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

   public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean isFocus, int row, int col) {
      Color beige = new Color(218, 217, 158);
      setBackground(beige);
      setText((value != null) ? value.toString() : "");
      return this;
   }
}

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

   protected JButton button;
   private DeleteButtonListener bListener = new DeleteButtonListener();

   public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
      super(checkBox);
      button = new JButton();
      button.setOpaque(true);
      button.addActionListener(bListener);
   }

   public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
      System.out.printf("row is: %d%n", row);
      bListener.setRow(row);
      bListener.setTable(table);

      // On réaffecte le libelle au bouton
      button.setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
      // On renvoie le bouton
      return button;
   }

   class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {

      private int row;
      private JTable table;

      public void setRow(int row) {
         this.row = row;
      }

      public void setTable(JTable table) {
         this.table = table;
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
         if (table.getRowCount() > 0) {
            System.out.println("coucou du bouton: " + ((JButton) event.getSource()).getText());
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(this.row);
            stopCellEditing();  // !! not sure if this will help or not.
            //!!  ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should post the exception stack trace as well. This seems as if the outside code (that calls your ButtonListener) has still references to the last row, which you remove, so, after return from ButtonListener, the your caller that still wants to access the last row gets an error. But the stack trace would be needed to find out what exactly triggers the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned by camickr, you forget to stop the cell edition when removing your row, making it possible to continue "editing" the cell and trigger another removal of the row on a no longer existing row (hence the index out of bounds exception)

Simply cancel the edition of  the button at the end. And as mentionned by camickr, no need to `fireTableDataChanged()`, `removeRow()` will take care of that.

See SSCCE (not so short actually, but I am lazy to trim some lines) for demo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TestJTable {

    public class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

        protected JButton button;
        private final DeleteButtonListener bListener = new DeleteButtonListener();

        /**
         * Constructeur avec une checkBox
         * 
         * @param checkBox
         * @param count
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
            // Par défaut, ce type d'objet travaille avec un JCheckBox
            super(checkBox);
            // On crée à nouveau notre bouton
            button = new JButton();
            button.setOpaque(true);
            // On lui attribue un listener
            button.addActionListener(bListener);

        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            // On précise le numéro de ligne à notre listener
            bListener.setRow(row);
            // Idem pour le numéro de colonne
            // On passe aussi le tableau en paramètre pour des actions
            // potentielles
            bListener.setTable(table);

            // On réaffecte le libelle au bouton
            button.setText(value == null ? "" : value.toString());
            // On renvoie le bouton
            return button;
        }

        class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {

            private int row;
            private JTable table;

            public void setRow(int row) {
                this.row = row;
            }

            public void setTable(JTable table) {
                this.table = table;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (table.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    // On affiche un message
                    System.out.println("coucou du bouton: "
                            + ((JButton) event.getSource()).getText());
                    ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(this.row);
                    ButtonEditor.this.cancelCellEditing();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static final String[] title = { "X", "Nom", "SRM", "Rend.", "%",
            "Kg", };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestJTable().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(title, 4);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getColumn("X").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
        table.getColumn("X").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements
            TableCellRenderer {

        private static final Color beige = new Color(218, 217, 158);

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean isFocus, int row,
                int col) {
            setBackground(beige);
            // On écrit dans le bouton ce que contient la cellule
            setText(value != null ? value.toString() : "");
            // on retourne notre bouton
            return this;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @djosimd, try doing a mouse pressed on a cell and while the mouse is still held down move the mouse off of the cell. You have a strange rendering problem because the cell is still in editing mode. Then try a mouse pressed on another cell. The row is deleted immediately. This is inconsistent behaviour and not a very good UI.

Answer (score 2):

Although this won't solve your problem, don't invoke fireTableDataChanged, that is the job of the TableModel.

The problem is somewhere in your TableEditor. I would guess you and not stopping cell editing.

Check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). It implements the renderer/editor for you. All you need to do is provide an Action to be invoked when you click on the button.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I've created an SSCCE and added it to his question. I'm seeing the error, but can't find the cause.

Comment: +1, @HovercraftFullOfEels As mentionned by camickr, he is not  stopping the cell edition, allowing the "edition" to occur once more after the row has been removed, hence the index out of bounds since the last row has already been removed.